# Proper API implementation when comparing two children of a parent type

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, instanceof

Given the following:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    // Makes this vehicle race another Vehicle and returns who wins the race.
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle);
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    @Override
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle) {
        // Different algorithms are used to determine who wins based on
        // what type otherVehicle is.
        if(otherVehicle instanceof Car) {
            // Use algorithm #1 to determine who wins the race
        } else if(otherVehicle instanceof Helicopter) {
            // Use algorithm #2 to determine who wins the race
        } else if(otherVehicle instanceof Motorcycle) {
            // Use algorithm #3 to determine who wins the race
        }

        // ...etc.
    }
}

public class Helicopter implement Vehicle {
    @Override
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle) {
        // Same problem as above with Car.
    }
}

public class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {
    // ... same problem here
}

... lots of other types of Vehicles
```

Since different algorithms are used to race `Car` vs. `Car`, `Car` vs `Helicopter`, etc. the implementation of the `race(Vehicle)` method becomes unsightly and full of `instanceof` checks... yuck.

There **must** be a more OO way of doing this...ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    // Makes this vehicle race another Vehicle and returns who wins the race.
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle);
    public Vehicle race(Helicopter otherVehicle);
    public Vehicle race(Motorcycle otherVehicle);
    public Vehicle race(Car otherVehicle);
}

public class Helicopter implement Vehicle {
    @Override
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle) {
        otherVehicle.race(this);
    }

    public Vehicle race(Helicopter heli) {

    }
    ...
}

public class Car implement Vehicle {
    @Override
    public Vehicle race(Vehicle otherVehicle) {
        otherVehicle.race(this);
    }

    public Vehicle race(Helicopter heli) {
        return heli;
    }
    ...
}


public static void Main(string args[]) {
    Vehicle car = new Car();
    Vehicle helicopter = new Helicopter();

    Vehicle winner = helicopter.race(car);
    // returns helicopter
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks @Johnbot (+1)! Although doesn't that violate lispkov substitution? or whatever principle states that the parent class should have no knowledge of its children? Thiughts?

Comment: It's not clean, that's for sure. You could go with a Race class and a IComparable interface on the vehicles to get a bit more abstraction.

Comment: Thanks again @Johnbot (+1) - would you mind posting some quick pseudo-code for that idea (Race/IComparable)? I'm having a tough time visualizing it. Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster [Implementing `equals` with subclassing (down at #4)](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) is a similar problem regarding the LSPrinciple. You also have to check whether you need to be symmetric(`a.race(b) == b.race(a)`), transitive (a > b, b > c == a > c) etc.  And depending on your algorithm, couldn't you make it like a [Top Trumps](http://www.mea.org.uk/news/eco-top-trumps-are-perfect-stocking-fillers) card game where you only compare properties defined by `Vehicle`? That would get rid of the dependency on other implementation of that interface.